# How to include local timezone details with current_timestamp as default value for a column in mysql

Tags: mysql, timezone, timestamp

```
mysql>create table login_log (login_log_id int(11),username varchar(20), login_date timestamp default current_timestamp)
```

how to include local timezone details for the login_date column as a default value so that whenever i insert a row in that table, timestamp along with timezone should be stored.
like this dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss TZhh:TZmm

Comment: use DATETIME instead of timestamp  in mysql

Answer (score 0):

Select change in date [image: select change]

Edit your date column in your database and change the default to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.
This should do the trick.
 [image: Timestamp]

Comment: I need current_timestamp along with the local timezone. Like this 16/06/2016 04:58:00 +05:30                                            here    +05:30 is the local timezone